# Error when running installXLSXsupport() for gdata package

Tags: r

I am trying to load the gdata package, but get the following error message:

```
gdata: Unable to locate valid perl interpreter
gdata: 
gdata: read.xls() will be unable to read Excel XLS and XLSX files unless the 'perl=' argument is used to specify the location of a
gdata: valid perl intrpreter.
gdata: 
gdata: (To avoid display of this message in the future, please ensure perl is installed and available on the executable search
gdata: path.)
gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by read.xls()
gdata: to support 'XLX' (Excel 97-2004) files.

gdata: Unable to load perl libaries needed by read.xls()
gdata: to support 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files.

gdata: Run the function 'installXLSXsupport()'
gdata: to automatically download and install the perl
gdata: libaries needed to support Excel XLS and XLSX formats.
```

I then tried running `installXLSXsupport()` as suggested, but get the following error:

```
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
```

I have tried various suggestions found on google (mainly specifying the perl argument when using `read.xls`), but none are working. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I'm missing, to be able to get `read.xls` function to work?

Comment: `installXLSXsupport` requires perl. It uses perl to load a perl module. The only thing installXLSXsupport does is install that missing module. So you should be searching  for how to install  a version of perl that does this on your unspecified OS. And do read the help page which states: `In particular, installXLSXsupport will fail for the version of perl included with the current RTools.zip package, which is not correctly configured to allow installation of additional perl packages. (The RTools version of perl is installed in a different directory than the perl configuration files expect.)`

Answer (score 1):

I have ran in this issue and I have a possible workaround.

Investigating which `perl` functions the `gdata::installXLSXsupport()` function calls, there is a `perl` section (in `gdata/inst/module_tools.pl`) that checks for the following modules:

```perl
# ...
    eval
      {
        require Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
    use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Utility qw(ExcelFmt);
        $HAS_Spreadsheet_ParseExcel=1;
        print "Loaded Spreadsheet::ParseExcel\n" if $VERBOSE;
      };
    eval
      {
        require Compress::Raw::Zlib;
        $HAS_Compress_Raw_Zlib=1;
        print "Loaded Compress::Raw::Zlib\n" if $VERBOSE;
      };
    eval
      {
        require Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
        $HAS_Spreadsheet_ParseXLSX=1;
        print "Loaded Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX\n" if $VERBOSE;
      };
# ...
```

For this reason I issued the following commands as root:

```sh
cpan init                                                                          
cpan Bundle::Compress::Zlib                                                        
cpan Spreadsheet::ParseExcel Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX
```

This workaround was tested with:

```
perl version: 5.30.0
R version: 4.0.2
R - gdata version: 2.18
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to add. It is important to make sure the correct perl executable is in your PATH (in R) when using `gdata`. It can be done in R using `Sys.which("perl")`.